# How do i solve the migw installation problem?

Tags: c++

[The message that is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTULG.png)

I have installed mingw and vs code editor ,but when i try to compile its showing a message of this kind ,please help me how to resolve this ,I have been trying from many days ,but I couldn't understand the problem

Comment: What does `g++ --version` command show in windows cmd ?

Comment: If you put that error message into your favorite search engine, what information can you get from that? Searching for e.g. `mingw undefined reference to winmain` should get you just the information you need.

Comment: For future questions please post errors and code as text not screenshots

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This error normally means "no main function", which doesn't seem to be the case here?

Comment: OP, make sure you only have a single version of MinGW installed, to avoid any possible conflicts. Also, GCC 6.3 that you currently have is *old*. Consider using a different MinGW distribution that provides an up-to-date version, like https://www.msys2.org/ or http://winlibs.com/

Comment: Yes, the dupe is informatiive but doesn't seem to apply to the OP

Comment: To the OP: since you have a `main` function defined you need to look beyond the answers, links and comments saying that it's usually a missing `main` function. The linked duplicate do have a couple of comments in replies to some answers that could provide a possible solution. And of course searching the broader Internet (as mentioned) should give you a lot more. Sure it might be tedious, but welcome to the normal everyday programmers world, that's what we do. :)